# What is the name of this GUI?

Tags: user-interface, crm, siebel

What is the name of the lower black bar that displays information, is it an applet or what?

Here a picture that contains that lower black horizontal bar:

I know it is a status bar, I mean in the context of Siebel what is the name of this control ?

[image]

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Status_bar ?

Comment: Your picture shows a scrollbar, but I think you mean a status bar.

Comment: I think this should be migrated to Super User

Comment: This question is relevant to Siebel programmers and administrators, and in a very lesser way, to Siebel users. I don't think it should be migrated anywhere, it fits better here than on SuperUser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the "**message bar**". Yes, not the most original name ever, but that's how the Siebel people named it. It's not an applet, it's another part of the user interface, like the menus or the toolbars.

You can use it to display messages to your application users, via the "message broadcasting" functionality. Here are a couple of links to the relevant Bookshelf docs, in case you want to learn how to enable and configure these messages:

- [Siebel 8.0 bookshelf](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B40099_02/books/AppsAdmin/AppsAdminMessageBroad.html)
- [Siebel 8.1/8.2 bookshelf](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14004_01/books/AppsAdmin/AppsAdminMessageBroad.html)

In a nutshell, to enable the functionality you'd have to go to "Administration - Server Configuration" > "Enterprises" > "Component Definitions" > "Application Object Manager" > "Component Parameters", and set the "Application Message Bar Flag" parameter to "TRUE".

Then, to administer the messages, you'd have to use the "Message Broadcasts" view on the "Administration - Communications" screen.